# How to concatenate string in django framework

Tags: python, html, django

I want to concatenate a string to get a product link in one of my django datatable columns.

I want a result like this:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003324927716.html

The product id is stored in my  mongodb database.
This is what I tried to write in my **datatable.html** but i get an empty column:

```
 {% for product in products %}
  <tr>
<td> 
 {% with "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/"|add:{{product.productId}}|add:".html" as template %}
 {% endwith %}
</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Then to make it as an href link as this syntax :

```
<td><a href="{{product.Productlinks }}"> Click here</a></td>
```

**views.py :**

```
def datatable_view(request):
    client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    db = client["aliexpress"]
    col = db["listproducts"]
    products = col.find()
    context = {'products' : products}
    return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
```

**models.py :**

```
class Datatable(models.Model):

    Title = models.CharField('Title',max_length=500),
    Price = models.DecimalField('Price',decimal_places = 3, max_digits = 10000),
    Currency = models.CharField('Currency',max_length=500),
    Stars = models.DecimalField('Stars',decimal_places = 3 , max_digits = 10000),
    Orders = models.PositiveIntegerField('Orders',max_length=500),
    Shipcost = models.CharField('Shipcost',max_length=500),
    Supplier = models.CharField('Supplier',max_length=500),
    Productlinks = models.CharField('Productlinks',max_length=700)
```

I am pretty new in using django and I will be so grateful if you help me in this isuue.
Thank you !

Comment: Sounds like something to do in Python code or in a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Add the logic in the `Product` model, not in the template. Templates should *not* be used for business logic.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to say

Comment: Can you share your function or class in your view.py that sends the data to the template?

Comment: I edit my question regarding your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simple, add a property in your `Product` model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def link(self):
        return 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/' + str(self.productId) + '.html'
```

`<td><a href="{{product.link}}"> Click here</a></td>`

**UPDATE**

You can make it even more simpe by doing this :

`<td><a href="https://www.aliexpress.com/item/{{product.productId}}.html">Click here</a></td>`

Comment: It make an  empty column

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please help in other tasks if I don't disturb you ?

Comment: @OuissalBELAOUNI sure

Comment: can we do a zoom call please if you are available ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72257373/how-to-modify-aliexpress-country-using-playwright can you help me with this task